# Can anyone tell me how to make a cartoon like hand with four fingers

Tags: modeling

I want to create hands for my model, but it must be in a cylinder shape.
There are so many tutorials in YT but can't find one I want.
Can anyone tell me how to model like this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modeling the hand is straightforward. Start with an eight-sided cylinder. Rotate it by -22.5° on the Z-axis so you can see 3 faces in the front view. Then remove the top n-gon, select the edge on one side and fill the hole with the <kbd>F</kbd> key. Press the key 3x and the hole should be filled.

[image: start with the cylinder]

Then select the 3 faces at the top that you just have created and extrude them and scale them up (<kbd>E</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>). Do this 4x to create the palm of the hand. You can import your image as a reference and adjust the vertices as needed in the front view. Enabled X-ray mode to select the front and the back vertices and move them around.

After you have created the palm do the same for the fingers. Select the top face and extrude it a few times to create the finger. Repeat the steps for all four fingers.

Finally, scale down the hand a bit on the Y-axis to flatten it. Use proportional editing or the sculpt brushes to get the shape you want.

[image: modeling the hand]

Comment: Thank you so much, mate!!